# Creating a staging table when the target table has autoincrement

Tags: redshift

Is it possible to create a staging table when the target table has an autoincrement ID key, and then merge it back in?

I've attempted this:

```
 CREATE  TEMP TABLE stage (like target);


insert
into
    stage
    (colA, colB, colC)
```

Where the `target` table has an autoincrement column `id`.  When I run this script, I get back the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Cannot insert a NULL value into column id
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Cannot insert a NULL value into column id
  code:      8007
  context:   query execution
  query:     896442
  location:  column:1
  process:   query1_51 [pid=15458]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was creating a staging table without using `LIKE TARGET`, from there I created a few queries to see what values were in the staging table vs the target table.  I then inserted those values into the target table, and dropped the staging table.

Thanks to @SqlZim for the help in tuning the query.